# Why not-cell div in css table has non-zero width in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-tables

Here's [presentation of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/4CGAm/). Clicking on "content" square toggles `display: table-cell` on the `pre-content` div. In IE10 and FF24 it does not make the red line visible at all, while in chrome 30 it does.

I'm trying to create dockable panel on full-window application which either floats on top, either is one of the two columns, and I'm docking the panel by switching classes: either one with `position: absolute`, either one with `display: table-cell`.

Why is there such a difference in behaviour? Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure on a fix, but I can tell you the reason is simply how different browsers render different elements. Apparently IE doesn't render table-cells in the same way that Chrome does. You will probably need to find a work-around or change methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be caused by your `#pre-content` divider being displayed as block by default. For some reason this has 11px width (I'm not sure why, however).

[image: Chrome Element Inspector Example]

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but can you not simply set this to not display at all by default instead?

```css
#pre-content:not(.table-cell) {
    display: none;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4CGAm/3/).

*Note that I've had to use the `not()` selector here as IDs have higher specificity than classes, and `#pre-content` would override `.table-cell`.*

Comment: It actually is not the problem with the start state of the fiddle, rather how it looks after making it displayed as div which is not displayed as `table-cell`. It turns out that only on chrome it takes more than 0px as empty div.